# Graph #N/A as Gap (Excel New Feature) through VBA

Tags: excel, vba, graph

Microsoft has (finally) added the feature to have #N/A show up as gaps in line charts. Problem is, this is an Office 365 Insider's only option at present.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/display-empty-cells-null-n-a-values-and-hidden-worksheet-data-in-a-chart-a1ee6f0c-192f-4248-abeb-9ca49cb92274

I have read that the graph may display correctly outside of 365 (e.g., in Excel 2016), but that the check box is simply not there.

1. Is there / what is the VBA code to toggle this setting for a graph object (assuming I have the option)?
2. Can this code be applied to a supported version of Excel, even if the check box is not visible?

Appreciate any insight into this.

Comment: *I have read that the graph may display correctly outside of 365* where did you read this? Might be instructive. It would seem unlikely that the code could apply in a previous version of Excel, as this presupposes a change to the object model, I'd expect a compile-time error like "Object does not support this method or property". The way I've always handled this in 2003-2016 Excel is to programmatically remove the line segments that otherwise connect to the "0" or Error value point.

Comment: From here: https://peltiertech.com/plot-blank-cells-na-in-excel-charts/

Is suggests that "This new feature has been rolled out not only to Office 365 subscribers, but also to regular Excel 2016 users. On my Office 365 laptop I have the full-blown Show #N/A As An Empty Cell behavior. On my non-Office-365 laptop, I get the new behavior, but I still do not have the new dialog, so I can’t toggle it on and off."

I was hoping I might be able to hit it from VBA by some off chance.

Comment: Does the chart appear correctly in non-365 environment (i.e., with the NA's plotted as blanks without line connectors)? If so, any chance you can extract the chart's XML and add it to this question? It may not be possible via API but there may be some, other ways to do it. Just curious :)

Comment: I do not have access to a 365 environment to try it in and then experiment on. Or else I would do a bunch of science projects!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not certain if this Chart option is available outside of Office365.

For reference, this is the UI mentioned in your link:

[image]

When I record a macro in O365:

**Toggling between the top three radio buttons produces:**

```
ActiveChart.DisplayBlanksAs = xlNotPlotted 'Gaps
ActiveChart.DisplayBlanksAs = xlZero 'Zero
ActiveChart.DisplayBlanksAs = xlInterpolated 'Connect Data Point With Line
```

**Toggling the checkbox `Show #N/A as an empty cell` it produces the following code:**

```
ActiveChart.DisplayValueNotAvailableAsBlank = True
```

**Toggling the last checkbox `Show data in hidden rows and columns` produces:**

```
ActiveChart.PlotVisibleOnly = True
```

**difference in Chart.xml**
When I toggle on "Show #N/A as an empty cell the chart's XML gains a new entry in the `<c:chart>` section:

```
        <c:extLst>
            <c:ext uri="{56B9EC1D-385E-4148-901F-78D8002777C0}" xmlns:c16r3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2017/03/chart">
                <c16r3:dataDisplayOptions16>
                    <c16r3:dispNaAsBlank val="1"/>
                </c16r3:dataDisplayOptions16>
            </c:ext>
        </c:extLst>         
    </c:chart>
```

That entry occurred after the `<c:dispBlansAs val="gap">` as well (which perhaps is necessary for this feature?

Here is the full  tag contents with "Gaps" chosen and "Show #N/A as an empty cell"

```
<c:chart><c:title><c:overlay val="0"/><c:spPr><a:noFill/><a:ln><a:noFill/></a:ln><a:effectLst/></c:spPr><c:txPr><a:bodyPr rot="0" spcFirstLastPara="1" vertOverflow="ellipsis" vert="horz" wrap="square" anchor="ctr" anchorCtr="1"/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:pPr><a:defRPr sz="1400" b="0" i="0" u="none" strike="noStrike" kern="1200" spc="0" baseline="0"><a:solidFill><a:schemeClr val="tx1"><a:lumMod val="65000"/><a:lumOff val="35000"/></a:schemeClr></a:solidFill><a:latin typeface="+mn-lt"/><a:ea typeface="+mn-ea"/><a:cs typeface="+mn-cs"/></a:defRPr></a:pPr><a:endParaRPr lang="en-US"/></a:p></c:txPr></c:title><c:autoTitleDeleted val="0"/><c:plotArea><c:layout/><c:lineChart><c:grouping val="standard"/><c:varyColors val="0"/><c:ser><c:idx val="0"/><c:order val="0"/><c:spPr><a:ln w="28575" cap="rnd"><a:solidFill><a:schemeClr val="accent1"/></a:solidFill><a:round/></a:ln><a:effectLst/></c:spPr><c:marker><c:symbol val="none"/></c:marker><c:cat><c:strRef><c:f>Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5</c:f><c:strCache><c:ptCount val="5"/><c:pt idx="0"><c:v>a</c:v></c:pt><c:pt idx="1"><c:v>b</c:v></c:pt><c:pt idx="2"><c:v>c</c:v></c:pt><c:pt idx="3"><c:v>d</c:v></c:pt><c:pt idx="4"><c:v>e</c:v></c:pt></c:strCache></c:strRef></c:cat><c:val><c:numRef><c:f>Sheet1!$B$1:$B$5</c:f><c:numCache><c:formatCode>General</c:formatCode><c:ptCount val="5"/><c:pt idx="0"><c:v>1</c:v></c:pt><c:pt idx="1"><c:v>2</c:v></c:pt><c:pt idx="2"><c:v>#N/A</c:v></c:pt><c:pt idx="3"><c:v>4</c:v></c:pt><c:pt idx="4"><c:v>5</c:v></c:pt></c:numCache></c:numRef></c:val><c:smooth val="0"/><c:extLst><c:ext uri="{C3380CC4-5D6E-409C-BE32-E72D297353CC}" xmlns:c16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chart"><c16:uniqueId val="{00000000-0572-4F99-B038-31D491665099}"/></c:ext></c:extLst></c:ser><c:dLbls><c:showLegendKey val="0"/><c:showVal val="0"/><c:showCatName val="0"/><c:showSerName val="0"/><c:showPercent val="0"/><c:showBubbleSize val="0"/></c:dLbls><c:smooth val="0"/><c:axId val="812746351"/><c:axId val="929183455"/></c:lineChart><c:catAx><c:axId val="812746351"/><c:scaling><c:orientation val="minMax"/></c:scaling><c:delete val="0"/><c:axPos val="b"/><c:numFmt formatCode="General" sourceLinked="1"/><c:majorTickMark val="none"/><c:minorTickMark val="none"/><c:tickLblPos val="nextTo"/><c:spPr><a:noFill/><a:ln w="9525" cap="flat" cmpd="sng" algn="ctr"><a:solidFill><a:schemeClr val="tx1"><a:lumMod val="15000"/><a:lumOff val="85000"/></a:schemeClr></a:solidFill><a:round/></a:ln><a:effectLst/></c:spPr><c:txPr><a:bodyPr rot="-60000000" spcFirstLastPara="1" vertOverflow="ellipsis" vert="horz" wrap="square" anchor="ctr" anchorCtr="1"/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:pPr><a:defRPr sz="900" b="0" i="0" u="none" strike="noStrike" kern="1200" baseline="0"><a:solidFill><a:schemeClr val="tx1"><a:lumMod val="65000"/><a:lumOff val="35000"/></a:schemeClr></a:solidFill><a:latin typeface="+mn-lt"/><a:ea typeface="+mn-ea"/><a:cs typeface="+mn-cs"/></a:defRPr></a:pPr><a:endParaRPr lang="en-US"/></a:p></c:txPr><c:crossAx val="929183455"/><c:crosses val="autoZero"/><c:auto val="1"/><c:lblAlgn val="ctr"/><c:lblOffset val="100"/><c:noMultiLvlLbl val="0"/></c:catAx><c:valAx><c:axId val="929183455"/><c:scaling><c:orientation val="minMax"/></c:scaling><c:delete val="0"/><c:axPos val="l"/><c:majorGridlines><c:spPr><a:ln w="9525" cap="flat" cmpd="sng" algn="ctr"><a:solidFill><a:schemeClr val="tx1"><a:lumMod val="15000"/><a:lumOff val="85000"/></a:schemeClr></a:solidFill><a:round/></a:ln><a:effectLst/></c:spPr></c:majorGridlines><c:numFmt formatCode="General" sourceLinked="1"/><c:majorTickMark val="none"/><c:minorTickMark val="none"/><c:tickLblPos val="nextTo"/><c:spPr><a:noFill/><a:ln><a:noFill/></a:ln><a:effectLst/></c:spPr><c:txPr><a:bodyPr rot="-60000000" spcFirstLastPara="1" vertOverflow="ellipsis" vert="horz" wrap="square" anchor="ctr" anchorCtr="1"/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:pPr><a:defRPr sz="900" b="0" i="0" u="none" strike="noStrike" kern="1200" baseline="0"><a:solidFill><a:schemeClr val="tx1"><a:lumMod val="65000"/><a:lumOff val="35000"/></a:schemeClr></a:solidFill><a:latin typeface="+mn-lt"/><a:ea typeface="+mn-ea"/><a:cs typeface="+mn-cs"/></a:defRPr></a:pPr><a:endParaRPr lang="en-US"/></a:p></c:txPr><c:crossAx val="812746351"/><c:crosses val="autoZero"/><c:crossBetween val="between"/></c:valAx><c:spPr><a:noFill/><a:ln><a:noFill/></a:ln><a:effectLst/></c:spPr></c:plotArea><c:plotVisOnly val="1"/><c:dispBlanksAs val="gap"/><c:extLst><c:ext uri="{56B9EC1D-385E-4148-901F-78D8002777C0}" xmlns:c16r3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2017/03/chart"><c16r3:dataDisplayOptions16><c16r3:dispNaAsBlank val="1"/></c16r3:dataDisplayOptions16></c:ext></c:extLst><c:showDLblsOverMax val="0"/></c:chart>
```

Comment: Accepted as it answers the question of "what is the VBA code". As an aside, no, I cannot trigger this through VBA in a non-365 Excel 2016. Well, it was worth a shot.

Comment: I figured that was going to be the case. I would imagine if they had the feature in their codebase, they probably wouldn't expose it to VBA before exposing it in the UI. Tough break :(

Comment: any chance you can extract the chart's XML and add it to this answer? Would be interesting to see what the XML attribute(s) were added, and whether this could be coerced some other way (non-VBA).

Comment: I did a quick diff toggling that "Show #N/A..." checkbox on and off. I have added where the diff occurred as well as the full contents of the `<c:chart>` tag inside the `chart1.xml`. Best of luck!